# How i can change this script from Java to Python

Tags: python, java, function, dictionary, stream

I was trying to transform this script from java to python, but I'm facing some technical issues to understand java's code.

the first class is a simple class, the name of it is a table.

```
class Table:

def __init__(self, name, number_tuple, size_tuple, nature):
    self.__name = name
    self.__number_tuple = number_tuple
    self.__size_tuple = size_tuple
    self.__nature = nature

def get_name(self):
    return self.__name

def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def get_number_tuple(self):
    return self.__number_tuple

def set_number_tuple(self, number_tuple):
    self.__number_tuple = number_tuple

def get_size_tuple(self):
    return self.__size_tuple

def set_size_tuple(self, size_tuple):
    self.__size_tuple = size_tuple

def get_nature(self):
    return self.__nature

def set_nature(self, nature):
    self.__nature = nature
```

The second class is the parser class, which I'm facing trouble to change it.
the first code is on java:

```
public class Parser {
 
Map<Integer, Table> tables;  

public Table searchTableByValue(String value) {

    Map<Integer, Table> result = this.tables.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(
        map -> value.equals(
        ((Table)map.getValue()).getName()
        ))
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            p -> (Integer)p.getKey(), p -> (Table)p.getValue()
        ));

    return (Table)result.values().toArray()[0];  
}
```

The issues that I can't understand to transform is

```
map -> value.equals(((Table)map.getValue()).getName()))
```

I have tried to work on python, but I didn't do much, the code is below

```
from operator import eq
from lazy_streams import stream
class Parser:

    self.tables = tables

    def is_equal(self, first, second):
        return eq(first, second)

    def search_table_by_value(self, value):
     
        cond = list(map(self.is_equal,value, (self.tables.values()).get_name()))

        result = stream(self.tables.copy().values()) \
                .filter(cond) \
       
    return result[0]
```

Comment: `Java` and `Python` are different and converting word-by-word can be wrong idea. For example in Python is preferred to keep value directly in `self.name` instead of `self.__name` and use directly `self.name` instead of `get_name()` and `set_name()`. And the same is with all your `list`, `map`, `filter`.

Comment: For what it's worth, `searchTableByValue` is a terrible name for a method that finds a table by its _name_.